# where is the railties folder in rails 2.3.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to go through the codes of a rails 2.3.9 application. I expect to have railties folder in  `app_root/vendor/rails/railties/` but I don't have this directory. In vendor directory I just have plugins directory. Where is this railties directory supposed to be?

I want to change the default port for the application but also go through the files needed for boot process

Comment: You may want to add some information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm editing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recall there being an app-local railties folder back in Rails 2.3.

Port configuration was handled differently; it was in the `server` script itself, [hardcoded in an options hash](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.9/railties/lib/commands/server.rb#L15)--I always just modified that.

Comment: Added a link to the options hash.